# How to update all xml attributes' value in an xml variable using t-sql?

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Let's have a sample snipet

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'
<a abb="122">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>
<a abb="344">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>
...
';
SELECT @xml;

--need to update abb to be 888 in @xml here

SELECT @xml;
```

We can update one attribute at a time as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338425/how-to-update-an-xml-attribute-value-in-an-xml-variable-using-t-sql). The new question is: How can we update all at-a-time occurences of attribute `abb`?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the XML to a table variable, replace each node separately and then combine them again.

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<a abb="122">
  <b></b>
 </a>
 <a abb="344">
  <b></b>
 </a>'

declare @T table (XMLCol xml)
insert into @T
select
  a.query('.')
from @xml.nodes('a') a(a)

update @T set
  XMLCol.modify('replace value of (/a/@abb)[1] with 888')

set @xml = (select XMLCol as [*]
            from @T
            for xml path(''))
```