# tsql how to split xml and insert them as rows

Tags: xml, t-sql

There was a question here ([How to update all xml attributes' value in an xml variable using t-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347890/how-to-update-all-xml-attributes-value-in-an-xml-variable-using-t-sql)) where the questioner wanted to split an xml variable into rows.

I have almost the same problem, but I'm storing the xmls in a table. Every row stores at least 1 xml node, sometimes more. I want to split them to separate rows, but it seems like .nodes('a') needs a scalar variable.

This is what I've tried:

```
declare @T table (XMLCol xml);

insert into @T values
('<a abb="122">
  <b></b>
 </a>
 <a abb="144">
  <b></b>
 </a>'),
 ('<a abb="222">
  <b></b>
 </a>
 <a abb="244">
  <b></b>
 </a>');

 select a.query('.') from @T.nodes('a') a(a);
```

What I want to achieve:
I have a table like this:

```
ID           XML
1            <a abb="122"><b></b></a><a abb="144"><b></b></a>
2            <a abb="222"><b></b></a><a abb="244"><b></b></a>
```

I want to convert it to something like that:

```
ID           XML
1            <a abb="122"><b></b></a>
2            <a abb="144"><b></b></a>
3            <a abb="222"><b></b></a>
4            <a abb="244"><b></b></a>
```

For that I want to write something that works like a simple

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this (if I understood your question correctly):

```
declare @xml xml = N'<a abb="122"><b></b></a><a abb="144"><b></b></a>'
select  @xml.query('/a/*')
```

If you want each b node to be shown as row, use this:

```
select x.items.query('.') from @xml.nodes('/a/b') as x(items)
```

Edit:
You can get data from your table variable like this:

```
select tbl.vals
from @T as t
cross apply (select x.items.query('.') from t.XMLCol.nodes('/a') as x(items)) as tbl(vals)
```

Comment: Hey!

The second one is what I want, but it only works with xml variable. My question is how can I make it work on a whole table, not just on a variable.

Comment: @Nandor: Try third one :)